# Weird NVIDIA graphic card issue

Tags: crash, nvidia-graphics-card

I have Nvidia 460 gtx (Cyclone OC, 768 MB) graphic card and about 6 months ago it started to randomly crash and it kept crashing until I installed different drivers (usually downgraded back to 275.33) and it always worked just fine for 2-6 weeks and then it started again. Installing different drivers doesn't work anymore and I have to unplug and plug it again to get it working. I'm 100% sure it's not overheating.

It usually only happens when browsing the internet (I'm using Firefox with hardware acceleration disabled).

I have contacted the vendor and they won't replace it until it's completely broken.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you are receiving a message saying that nvlddmkm stopped responding and the display driver recovered, possibly followed by the same message numerous times until you get a blue screen, then you're not alone. Just to see how common this is [take a look at a search](http://www.bing.com/search?q=nvlddmkm) that only includes the nVidia driver name.

I had this error with my GTX 560, it's a problem with no real solution. From what I can gather the issue isn't related to nVidia in particular and also occurs with AMD cards. It's the way the new driver model works from Vista onwards. As for what to suggest, this is tricky as there are a million different suggestions although one useful thread on the nVidia forum is [this](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=223716). I'm unsure if anything there will help you - it didn't me, but I explained the issue to EVGA who had no issues replacing my card to the GTX 560 Superclocked, and along with the latest drivers (IIRC 290.X), I've had no problems for quite a number of weeks... touch wood...